# Does $\to$ imply that the function is defined at the point?

Tags: calculus

$g \to 0$ as $x \to 0$

Does this notation imply that $g$ is *defined* at $0$?

Comment: It is the 20.000th question in 'calculus' :)

Comment: The answer is "no".

Answer (score 1):

This means that $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=0$.  So, $g$ needn't be defined at $0$. For instance
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2(x-1)}{x}=0
$$
but the function is not defined at $0$.

Comment: Or, $g(x)=x\log x$ is another example.